# How To Create Google PageRank Checker By PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagerank

I want a Google PageRank Checker for check pageRank a url that if was larger of 5, return (result) it is TRUE, else (less of 5) return (result) is FALSE. how is it by PHP or codeigniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mark Woodman** has created a nifty class which lets you query Google pagerank info in PHP and above. The complete classes are available [here](http://code.google.com/p/popstats/).

Here is a detailed tutorial:

[**Google Pagerank in PHP**](http://www.codediesel.com/php/google-pagerank-in-php/)

**EDIT:**

Here is a class of google page rank checker on [**php classes**](http://www.phpclasses.org):

[**PHP Classes: Google Page Rank Checker Class**](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2682-PHP-Retrieve-the-Google-page-rank-of-a-given-URL.html)

and here is another blog doing the same thing:

http://davidwalsh.name/google-pagerank

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note the big box up top: "Due to recent changes made by Google in its Page Rank processing the following library doesn’t work." (The referenced fusionswift.com page doesn't exist either.)

Comment: @duskwuff - What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Above david walsh script is not working. I am using SEOStats library present in GITHub.

Source: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/#brief-example-of-use

Answer (score 0):

In response/addition to [Vivek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773428/624466)

> Above david walsh script is not working. I am using SEOStats library
>   present in GITHub.
>   Source: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/#brief-example-of-use

Actually you don't need to use the full library. SEOstats internally uses a standalone Google PageRank class that can be used as follows:

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://somedomain.com/';  
  $pr  = new GTB_PageRank($url);

  $rank = $pr->getPageRank();

  printf("The Google Pagerank of %s is %s.", $url, $rank);
```

The nice thing about this class, as I think, is that it supports all existing PageRank hashing algorithms (awesome, jenkins, jenkins2 and IE) and has some advanced features built in, such as suggested Toolbar-TLD and more.

You can get the code here: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/blob/master/SEOstats/Services/3rdparty/GTB_PageRank.php